# Do we need to set all vuetify breakpoints?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, overflow

I want to set a v-col with

`lg="6" md="6" sm="6"`

and keep `mx-auto` in `xlOnly`

But when I do it and I am on an extra large monitor the v-col takes 6 columns when it should be much smaller with `mx-auto`

Does anyone have an idea on how I could solve this problem
thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need to set all vuetify breakpoints?

You don't need to set all breakpoints. As breakpoint system done with the mobile-first approach - you can set just 1 smaller breakpoint, sm="6" in your example. It will take 6 columns on all screens equal or higher than sm (sm + md + lg + xl), if no override is presented on bigger screens. So if you'll add lg="8" it will take 6 columns on sm + md and 8 columns on lg and xl. Source: `SM - Changes the number of columns on small and greater breakpoints`, [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-col/#props-sm)

> keep mx-auto in xlOnly

You can do it with **mx-xl-auto** - red it as `{property}{direction}-{breakpoint}-{size}`. [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/#breakpoints)

> on an extra large monitor the v-col takes 6 columns when it should be much smaller

There is no reason for the column to be *much smaller*, mx-auto sets main axis (horizontal in your case) margins to auto, so it's centering the col. It's not affecting width in any way. You can try to add **xl="auto"**, it should let block take only space it needs. If it will not look properly - just set the desired amount of columns (example: **xl="4"**)

Comment: The issue is I have 5 components that need to be the same width so I can't hard code the exact number of cols as you said since I can't divide the 12 cols in 5 equal parts and xl="auto" as you said only takes the space it needs but it does not solve my issue I want them to share equal width and to entirely fill the v-row

Comment: And using mx-xl-auto in the same time as lg="6" md="6" sm="6" the mx-xl-auto gets overriden